# Why can't I list items on Facebook Marketplace as all my pages?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-marketplace

I currently run a few different Facebook pages, and when I go to post something on Facebook Marketplace, I'm given the option of posting as those pages:

[image: Two of the pages I run]

However these are not all the pages I run. In fact, these two pages relate to a mobile app I've written, primarily targeted at people outside of Australia, so I'd never actually sell anything from those pages.

But now I've started up a new page for a hobby of mine (selling retro gaming stuff) and want to sell things to people in the local area. However, as shown in the screenshot, the page I want, doesn't actually appear.

Do I need to set something in my Facebook page settings in order to sell things as my page? I've got an email, website, privacy policy, opening hours and category set (but no phone number or address -- none of my pages have those set because I'm not a physical store)

EDIT: As I've only just recently started my page, I only have one like (myself). I was wondering if you have to reach a certain amount of likes before your page shows up, but I just added another page I'm an admin of, which has ~2,000 likes, to [Facebook Business](https://business.facebook.com/) and it doesn't show up.

Comment: This is a good question. Is there any relationship that you've seen between the pages that can and can't post? I've never seen pages post in marketplace as I thought it was C2C only but maybe that's not  the case

Comment: @RayB I can't find any relationship between the pages. At first I thought it was the page category, but no matter what I set it to, it doesn't show up in the list. I did see someone ask if it was a gradual roll out thing Facebook were doing, but it's been this way for over a month, so I don't know?